# JavaScript querySelector of a concrete HTML class

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If AJAX returns multiple records, that have the following construction, how can I select the value of the specific input tag with the 'review'?

```js
`<div class="record">
<div class="record_item">${element.name}</div> 
<div class="record_item">${element.type}</div> 
<div class="record_item">${element.country}</div> 
<div class="record_item">${element.region}</div> 
<div class="record_item"><input type="text" class="review" name="review"></div>
<button onclick="ajaxReview('${element.id}')">Review</button>
</div>`).join('');
```

Comment: Is that a string or HTML? What is `join('')` doing in this case? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the use of `join()` here ??

Comment: This is an extract from the JS code

Comment: your  JS code looks strange - when you copy-paste it to browser - it will return error - is invalid...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".record");

const getInputNameTag=el.children[4].children[0].name

if(getInputNameTag==="review"){
 console.log("Value from input: ", el.children[4].children[0].value)
}
```

```html
<div class="record">
  <div class="record_item">${element.name}</div> 
  <div class="record_item">${element.type}</div> 
  <div class="record_item">${element.country}</div> 
  <div class="record_item">${element.region}</div> 
  <div class="record_item">
    <input type="text" class="review" value="asdf" name="review"/>
  </div>
  <button onclick="ajaxReview('${element.id}')">Review</button>
</div>
```

```
const el = document.querySelector(".record");

const getInputNameTag=el.children[4].children[0].name

if(getInputNameTag==="review"){
    console.log(el.children[4].children[0].value)
}
```

You can select element and loop through all children and see if they have input field with 'review' name to make it more dynamic in case you change your form.

EDIT: Added a code snippet

Comment: What if I have multiple <div class="record">'s. How do I do it then?

Comment: Just loop through each "record" and check if they have input tag, as a child, with 'review' name.

Comment: Could you provide some code? When I iterate records with for/foreach loop, it gets the value of say first element, no matter what button is pressed

Comment: for(let i=0;i<el.children.length;i++){
 if(el.children[i].children.length>0){
  for(let j=0;j<el.children[i].children.length;j++){
    if(el.children[i].children[j].tagName=="INPUT" && el.children[i].children[j].name==="review"){
    console.log("Input value: "+el.children[i].children[j].value)
    }
    }
 }
 
}